# resizing PixelData of DicomData using EmguCV(C#)

Tags: c#, emgucv, fo-dicom

i have issue with cv2.resize as you see in the example below. it seems that i use the api in the wrong way, or i missed some declarations.
According to the API, the are InputArray, OutPutArray, which I didn't really understand how to use those. I tried the Cv2.Resize as you can see in my code.

Does anyone have a solution how i can use the cv2.resize correctly??.
Thnak you.

```
DicomFile dicomFile_ = DicomFile.Open(pathOfFileList[0],FileReadOption.ReadAll);
//Read Dicom Dataset

var pixelData_ = dicomFile_.Dataset.GetValues<byte>(DicomTag.PixelData);
//Get Pixel Data for each slice 

Mat outputArray = new Mat();

Cv2.Resize(pixelData_.Length, outputArray, new Size(512,512),0.5,0.5, InterpolationFlags.Area);
//I try to resize the pixelData_, which its resolution 1024 pixels*1024 pixels(rows*columns), but it does not work, it seems that im using the cv2.resize in the wrong way.

var t = outputArray.ToBytes();
//i check if the size of the outputarray, which are 1358 bytes!!
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uohdO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just input the length of the pixeldata array as the input for resize. You need to create a `Mat` with the correct size and color depth See [Create an Image](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Creating_Image)

If you only need to resize images with a specific color depth (i.e. 16 bit grayscale) I would suggest using the older CV.x 2 Image class. I think this is easier to understand:

```
var img = new Image<Gray, ushort>(width, height);
img.Bytes = source.Data;
var resizedImage = img.Resize(newWidth, newHeight, Inter.Cubic);
var resizedBytes = resizedImage.Bytes;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works as expected!